# how to make a user to have more than one role in session

Tags: codeigniter, roles

I have in my DB different user roles. When user register, it may insert in DB more than one role. But when I save it in session, it saves only one role. In some example, user has 2 roles - student and customer, but it is only shown as student.

My login controller is:

```html
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {
//some code
 public function login ()
    {
            
     $this->load->model('user_model');
        $user=$this->user_model->login();
        if(count($user) > 0) 
        {
                $this->load->library('session'); 
            
                 $data = array(
                    'username' => $user['username'],
                    'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE
                
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        
            $user_role=$this->user_model->user_role();

            $role=$this->session->set_userdata($user_role);

            $user_role = $this->session->userdata('role_id');


            if($user_role == 1)
            {
                  
                 redirect('student/index');
            } 
//and so on for other roles
    }
}
}
```

In my model I use "row_array". If I use result_array(), there's notice: "undefined index username, user_id in Controller". My model is:

```html
 public function login()
    {
          
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',sha1($this->input->post('password')));
        $result=$this->db->get('users');
   
    return $result->row_array();
   
    }
 public function user_role() 
{
   
    $this->db->select('role_id');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata['user_id']);
    $result=$this->db->get('user_roles');
        return $result->result_array();
   
}
```

Comment: You either need to have `$user_role` be an array of all the roles that user has, or you can define your roles by powers of two and use bitwise operators on them. So student = 1, teacher = 2, admin = 4, both admin and teacher = 2+4 = 6. Then `if($user_role & 1)` (note single &) will be true if the student bit is set for that user. Probably easier to use an array, though.

Comment: user_role[] is array. I use them in this way student=1, teacher=2, customer=3 and so on. I redirect them to the proper pages, but my idea is when you have registered as a teacher and a customer in the same time, you should see pages both student's and customer's. I have made this in DB - different user roles see different pages, but in my project this user is shown only as student in session.

Comment: can you tell why you have to store roles in session? maybe we can find another solution.

Comment: what I have known is that session value is a single value; you cannot store array or list object. but if it is what you have to do, you can store value like "id1, id2, id3" and when you use it you need to split it and get actual value.

Comment: I thought I might use session for more than one role, but if it could not, then I should think of another decision. I want when user log in, and if he is student and customer at the same time, to see these pages which are both for student and customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save array inside session.
You can do this way

```
$user_role=$this->user_model->user_role();//lets assume it returns the roles array
$this->session->set_userdata('roles'$user_role);//now you can set it inside roles varibale which contains the role array

//now to get the value from session use this

$roles=$this->session->userdata('roles');
//now roles contains the array of roles
//check your current roles info in the $roles array
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: yes, but my user_role() function return $result->row_array(); If I changed it as $result->result_array(); it doesn't work.

Comment: It will work now.But You need to save it to session as I did.As your current roles will be in array so you need to find your current role id inside the array.You cannot check simple `if($user_role == 1)`

Comment: How can I check in my session when it is array if 2 roles are saved in it. - var_dump() what in my example?

Comment: Please add your user_model with your question. var dump the output if you return `result_array` so that I can know the column names. You can do it lots of way. I may help you one way